# defining type class instance on GADT

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt

Consider the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Test where

data Nat
    = Z
    | S Nat
    deriving Show

data Test foo (n :: Nat) where
    Final :: Test foo n
    Step :: foo n -> Test foo (S n) -> Test foo n

instance Show (foo n) => Show (Test foo n) where
    show Final           = "final"
    show (Step bar step) = show bar ++ show step
```

where `Test` is a GADT depending on a type parameter `foo`, which has kind `Nat -> *`.

The code above does not compile and I have the following error

```
• Could not deduce (Show (foo ('S n))) arising from a use of ‘show’
  from the context: Show (foo n)
    bound by the instance declaration at src/Test.hs:18:10-42
• In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show step’
  In the expression: show bar ++ show step
  In an equation for ‘show’:
         show (Step bar step) = show bar ++ show step
   |
20 |     show (Step bar step) = show bar ++ show step
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I state that `Show (foo n)` holds for every `n`, so that the compiler accepts it when it looks for `Show (foo (S n))`?

Comment: `class ShowAllNats f where showNat :: f (n :: Nat) -> String`?

Comment: thanks @DanielWagner! That seems to work! I'm wondering if there is a more natural way to do that, where I don't have to define a new class

Comment: Okay, I've fleshed that out into an answer -- along with another approach that uses an extra data type rather than an extra class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be a natural way:

```
class ShowAllNats f where showNat :: f (n :: Nat) -> String
instance ShowAllNats foo => Show (Test foo n) where
    show Final = "final"
    show (Step bar step) = showNat bar ++ show step
```

One can avoid an additional type class by existentially quantifying:

```
data Some f where Some :: f (n :: Nat) -> Some f
instance Show (Some foo) => Show (Test foo n) where
    show Final = "final"
    show (Step bar step) = show (Some bar) ++ show step
```